# Problem using command "ng new my-app" with updated @angular/cli

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, npm

npm version 7.5.4 detected. The Angular CLI temporarily requires npm version 6 while upstream issues are addressed.

Please install a compatible version to proceed (`npm install --global npm@6`).
For additional information and alternative workarounds, please see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19957#issuecomment-775407654

Comment: As mentioned in the error message you've copied and pasted here, you have to install npm v6 instead of v7.

Answer (score 1):

### **Update**

The issue is closed and the problem solved

NPM 7.5.6 or greater.
Angular CLI 9.1.15, 10.2.3, 11.2.2, 12.0.0-next.2 or greater (within each major version).

#### if you still having problems use:

Hi you can bypass the error using `ng new --skip-install` <-- Workaround

Unfortunately is not the best approach is downgrade node and npm , stay tune here is the open issue :https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19957

If you want to use **schematics** the workaround will doesn't work ,please downgrade